# php datalist like datalist in jsf

Tags: php

I am looking for a php solution to list members of an object in a list like in jsf.

[Link of jsf datatable example. Scroll halfway down to see result picture](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/)

this is what I want to get but I didnt find any simple way like in jsf.

there you have a tag called "dataTable". with it you can do this:

```
 <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
        #{eachproduct.orderNo}
 </h:column>


 <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Product Name</f:facet>
        #{eachproduct.productName}
 </h:column>
```

you can also add a button in each cell per item.

```
 <h:column>
       <h:commandButton value="DELETE" type="submit" 
        action="#{eachproduct.delteProduct()}" />           
 </h:column>
```

Explaination:
The tag dataTable has a "value" and a "var".
the value needs a list with objects, in this case it is
value="#{data.productList}".
this means that the object "date" has a list called "product list

the var need just a String, to work with listItems.
I called it "eachproduct" so in each colum I can say "eachproduct.prudctName" or calling
other members of each product like price, quantity and so on.
you can call it what every you want.

this is what I look for in php.
is there also such a simple solution in php?
how can you do that in php? 
the simpler the solution the better

A simple example would be nice

thanks

Comment: so you are actually looking for a foreach loop?

Comment: datatable is not a foreach loop, its an automaticaly generated list which lists all informations of a given list

Comment: SO you want to have the exact same syntax? OR similar syntax (e.g. my foreach)

Comment: I dont want to the exact syntax, just hoped if there is a short way in php like in jsf but I guess theres not. so how would you do that to get the same result and also to be able to add buttons in each table cell if you want to. please take a look at the picture at the link, there you can see the jsf list that is generated automaticaly. an example would be nice

Comment: will do some tests and upload them if I find the time